# update Apache Ant on CentOS

Tags: linux, ant, centos

I need to update Apache Ant on my server.

I downloaded the newest Ant, built it, and (I thought) installed it. But when when I check it says the old version is still installed.

How do I update/replace the previous version of Apache Ant on a CentOS 5.? server?

take care,
lee

Comment: Where does it install to? It's possible that it's installed correctly, but your `PATH` is set so that the old version would still be used before your new one.

Comment: Hello,  When installing, I have set the ANT_HOME path to the new install. I've installed ANT on several systems where it was not previously installed and setting this ANT_HOME path has always worked.

Comment: Sorry...I install it to /usr/local/ant  .

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned it's probably getting picked up in your path. Post the output from echo $PATH

Answer (score 1):

To configure your CentOS after installing a new version of Apache Ant, proceed to the following steps:

1. Locate the directory where the new Ant is located
2. Set the `ANT_HOME` environment variable to this directory
3. Add `$ANT_HOME/bin` to your `PATH`

P.S. To modify environment variables, you may edit the /etc/environment file, and reboot, or modify your local `.bashrc`. Look at your current environment variables by analyzing the output of `printenv`, e.g., to see the current value of PATH and then add the Ant path to it, e.g.

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/bin:/usr/local/ant/bin`